# How can i change value of clicked button after open a bootstrap modal using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple buttons where i clicked than open a bootstrap modal with clicked button value, its working fine. Now i want to change value of clicked button when close bootstrap modal.

What i tried:-

```js
 $("input").click(function(e){
  var idClicked = e.target.id;
  $('#myModal').modal('show').find('.modal-title').text(idClicked);
 });
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
   <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Submit1" />
        <input id="btn2" type="button" value="Submit2" />
                
                
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submitModalBtn">submit</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just save the clicked button `id` and then on modal `close` event, you can change the `value` attribute based on the saved button `id`. Check out my fiddle. For now, I just changed the value to `someOtherValue` of the clicked button. You can change it to your expected value.

Please note, there can be multiple ways to perform this action. Kindly let me know if this is not what you are expecting.

```js
var clicked_button_id = '';
$("input").click(function(e){
    clicked_button_id = $(this).attr('id');
  var idClicked = e.target.id;
  $('#myModal').modal('show').find('.modal-title').text(idClicked);
 });
  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#"+clicked_button_id).val('someOtherValue');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
   <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Submit1" />
        <input id="btn2" type="button" value="Submit2" />
                
                
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submitModalBtn">submit</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code:

```
    <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Submit1" />
                                <input id="btn2" type="button" value="Submit2" />


<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
<input type="hidden" id="hdncurrent" >
        Modal body..
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submitModalBtn">submit</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
$("input").click(function(e){

        var idClicked = e.target.id;
        $('#myModal').modal('show').find('.modal-title').text(idClicked);
$("#hdncurrent").val(idClicked);
           $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

                $("#" + $("#hdncurrent").val()).attr("value","test")
            })
    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery will be like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
          $("input").click(function(e){
    var idClicked = e.target.id;
    $('#myModal').modal('show').find('.modal-title').text(idClicked);
    $(".close").click(function(){
      var btid="#"+idClicked;
   $(btid).val(idClicked);

  });
  });
  </script>
```